# Full Quality For Video Upload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Im picking a video from UIImagePicker, the video is then being uploaded to my server. I want the quality of the video to remain the same. As of right now the video has a bit less quality compared to the one i took directly off my phone, and it is a smaller resolution.

here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)video:(id)sender{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.mediaTypes =  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}



- (NSData *)generatePostDataForData:(NSData *)uploadData
{
// Generate the post header:
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithCString:"--AaB03x\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;     name=\"upload[file]\"; filename=\"somefile\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// Get the post header int ASCII format:
NSData *postHeaderData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding  allowLossyConversion:YES];

// Generate the mutable data variable:
NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:[postHeaderData length] ];
[postData setData:postHeaderData];

// Add the image:
[postData appendData: uploadData];

// Add the closing boundry:
[postData appendData: [@"\r\n--AaB03x--" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

// Return the post data:
return postData;
}

- (void)post:(NSData *)fileData
{

NSData *videoData = fileData;
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.site.com/scripts/upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".mov\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{ 
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//assign the mediatype to a string 
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

//check the media type string so we can determine if its a video
    NSLog(@"got a movie");
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    [self post:webData];


}
```

setting the pickers quality to high i thought would do it, i guess not. I have the option to export in 720p, but i want iphone 4s's to upload in full 1080p.

Any help would be great. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't skip the annoying compression step, UIImagePicker insists on doing it. You *can* get at the high quality video by using the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL key, however the long compression step is a deal breaker for me.

So go log a bug, then check out this excellent [drop in replacement](https://github.com/guicocoa/photopicker-ios).

Comment: Okay, i guess ill use this instead then. Thanks :D

Comment: @Rhythmic How can we the get absolute file path from UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL, i am trying to use photopicker-ios but it does not return uiimagepickercontrollermediaurl

Comment: I don't know, I ended up writing a replacement photo/video library browser.